# EF4, CodeFirst and Respository Pattern - Difference between using DbSet & DataContext

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

Trying to migrate my existing EF 4.2 project to use the Repository and Unit of Work patterns. In many people's samples I see them use the DbSet collections in the repositories, but to me this appears limiting as I can't use things like .Include(). Then again there are other samples using the DataContext (like this one http://www.efekaptan.com/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-code-first-4.1).

So... is there a reason why I wouldn't want to use the DataContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Include` with `DbSet<T>`. You should reference `DbContext` in your repository (pass it to repository instance through constructor) because it is required for more advanced operations. Storing reference to `DbSet<T>` is just simplificatoin / optimization to avoid calling `Set<T>()` on the context each time you want to access it.

You must not create instance of the context in the repository implementation (as showed in your linked question because it would go against Unit of Work.